# Accessing the struct members inside a std::variant

Tags: c++, std-variant

I've got a std::variant, which has as alternatives two different structs.
Now I need to fill it with data for one alternative (which i know at runtime), but it has to be in a way, that it's possible to write the elements in the struct separately.
Obviously, this can't work:

```
struct ContainerOne {
    uint8_t x;
};

struct ContainerTwo {
    uint8_t y;
    uint8_t z;
};

std::variant<ContainerOne, ContainerTwo> ContainerCollection;                   // CHOICE
ContainerCollection.x = 20;   // Error
```

Is there another way to achieve this? Maybe a way to, if i know the alternative i want to write to, tell the variant which structure it has or something like this?

The only way I could figure out is making a casted reference for the memory space of the variant and use it to write into it. Problem is that this makes no use of the methods of the variant, so the index isn't set automatically. Also setting the index in the same way is difficult, because somehow the size of the index variies over different variants (sometimes one byte, sometimes 8 bytes):

```
ContainerOne &ContainerOneRef = *(reinterpret_cast<ContainerOne*>(&ContainerCollection));

uint8_t* newptr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&ContainerCollection) + sizeof(ContainerCollection) - 0x01; // jump to the end of variant and one byte back, in the case the index is 1 Byte
*newptr = 0x01;

ContainerOneRef.x = 20;
```

Or is there maybe a way to find out what's the size of the index?

Comment: what you're trying to do there  is UB... also memory configuration of `std::variant ` may vary

Comment: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit)

Answer (score 1):

read about [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get)

And your code become smt like

```
struct ContainerOne {
    uint8_t x;
};

struct ContainerTwo {
    uint8_t y;
    uint8_t z;
};
int main()
{   
    std::variant<ContainerOne, ContainerTwo> ContainerCollection; 
    ContainerCollection = ContainerOne{1};
    std::get<ContainerOne>(ContainerCollection).x = 2;
    std::cout << std::get<ContainerOne>(ContainerCollection).x;
    return 0;
}
```

***P.S.*** And you have to remember that in `std::variant`, if you do not explicitly specify the type of structure (you call an empty constructor), then the variable is initialized by the default
constructor of the first type, so in your case it would be `ContainerOne`

Comment: That's a good suggestion, problem is that the structs in the end don't just have one or two elements, but bigger, different branched data structures, like another struct in another struct, or strings, or enum classes and so on.. So the first line with the initialisation must initialize this structures in a good way

Comment: @Gabriel This doens't matter. If you want to access some type, you should use ```std::get``` to access it. If you don't know your current type, than you can call ```ContainerCollection.index()``` to get index of current type and use it as template argument, or use ```std::visit``` to specify behaviour for every possible type

Comment: @Gabriel you can `auto & containerOne = std::get<ContainerOne>(ContainerCollection);` and then use `containerOne` as much as you like

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but it seems like you want to use std::get.

```
struct ContainerOne {
    uint8_t x = 0;
};

struct ContainerTwo {
    uint8_t y = 0;
    uint8_t z = 0;
};

int main() {


std::variant<ContainerOne, ContainerTwo> ContainerCollection;

ContainerCollection = ContainerOne();

std::get<ContainerOne>(ContainerCollection).x = 1;

ContainerCollection = ContainerTwo();

std::get<ContainerTwo>(ContainerCollection).y = 2;
std::get<ContainerTwo>(ContainerCollection).z = 3;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of dispatching at runtime to choose proper value based on returned index of active element ( member function `index()`). E.g. if we offer choices for every type and use `std::get`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <variant>

struct ContainerOne {
    uint8_t x;
};

struct ContainerTwo {
    uint8_t y;
    uint8_t z;
};
              
using ContainerType = std::variant<ContainerOne, ContainerTwo>;

void init_ContainerOne(ContainerType& v) {
    std::get<ContainerOne>(v).x = 20;
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

void init_ContainerTwo(ContainerType& v) {
    std::get<ContainerTwo>(v) = {};
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

decltype(&init_ContainerOne) dispatch[] =  { init_ContainerOne,  init_ContainerTwo };


int main()
{
   std::variant<ContainerOne, ContainerTwo> container  = ContainerOne{};
    
   dispatch[container.index()](container);
}
```

C++17 offers [std::visit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) which makes infrastructure simpler to build